# How should I handle this CSS Inheritance conundrum?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a class of images called glyphs that appear through out my site. Once upon a time they were all called just called `glyph`. They used to only appear in one box. That box was a specific size and I used a javascript method to make sure the text always fit and the glyphs were always about the same height as the rest of the text. This was easy to do and the glyphs started off with a default due to my style sheet.

Now, I've decided to include multiple boxes per page with variable amounts of text. Each box gets sized independently. I've tried delaying the sizing routine, but this is highly reliant on a user's connection speed. If I don't run the sizing routine then things don't look right at all, so I'd at least like to pick a default starting size for everything. Of course, you can't size stuff with javascript until it has been loaded. Snake eats tail.

So basically, now that I have more than one box, each glyph gets a class glyph:1, glyph:2, etc. This number can go as large as the number of user submitted items on my site. How does CSS handle this? These items basically need two class names as far as I can see. But I'm pretty sure that's not allowed.

What I need: Set all images classes that begin with "glyph:" to 1em

This doesn't exist, right? glyph:*

Also, : is probably bad to use in a css class name, huh?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use the : symbol.  you can have more than one class for an element so do it like so

```
<div class="glyph glyph-1">Foo</div>
<div class="glyph glyph-2">Foo</div>
<div class="glyph glyph-3">Foo</div>
<div class="glyph glyph-4">Foo</div>
```

Comment: I've never seen this before, wouldn't this just be a single class?

Comment: No, any element can have more than one class http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/qt/tipcssmulticlas.htm

Comment: +1 @Kirk You can add style a particular element by selecting both classes `.glyph.glyph-4 {}`.

Comment: @iambriansreed - note that this syntax doesn't work in IE6 (not that anyone should be using IE6 any more, but just saying, just in case)

Comment: @Spudley Probably doesn't work on a Commodore 64 either, just saying.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, you shouldn't use the colon symbol in class names. Hyphens and dashes are the only punctuation that is sensible to use.

It is possible to use colons in classes and escape them in your CSS code, but it gets really messy and is unnecessary.

Secondly (and this is where I'll go further than the other answers), if you're generating unique class names for your elements then you're probably doing something wrong.

The `id` attribute is there to give your elements a unique name; the `class` is intended to allow you to apply the same class (or classes) to multiple elements, thus allowing you to style all those elements the same. You probably know this already; I guess what I'm saying is that it sounds like you should be using `id` rather than `class`.

Next: You say you're pretty sure two class names is not allowed, but in fact it is allowed. It is perfectly permissible to have `class="glyph bob"` and your element will pick up styles from both class `glyph` and class `bob`. You can have as many classes as you like. I would still say, however, that if you want to give them unique names, it should be an ID.

You also ask for CSS syntax to set all the `glyph*` classes. Again, you're wrong: this syntax *does* exist, via the [extended attr syntax](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/selector_attributeAdvanced.html):

```
[class^="glyph"] {
    /*styles here for classes beginning with 'glyph'
}
```

You talk about delaying the sizing routine, and the problems that introduces. One solution to this could be to have the items hidden entirely until the browser has finished working out how they should look. You could even fade them into view or something to make it look like it was a deliberate effect.

But after all that, I'm left wondering why you're putting glyphs in images and sizing them independently? It all sounds a bit odd; your description in the question leaves me wondering what you're trying to achieve.

Have you considered using scalable graphics (SVG/VML) or a custom font for your glyphs, rather than images? If you used a custom font, you could simply specify the font size as normal, and let the browser work it all out.

Hope some of that was helpful.

Comment: Unfortunately there is often usually more than one glyph per box, so it is not possible to use ID easily. I'd have to keep an entire associative array when the stuff is created in php and pass it on to javascript to know what belonged where. The class solution above turned out to be best. I'm just a tad unfamiliar when it comes to css. I'd be up for finding out about your other ideas. Everything would make sense if you looked at the site: http://gumonshoe.net/magic

Comment: @kirk: use the ID on the outer container elements, and then just `class=glyph` on the glyphs themselves; you can still reference the ID on the container element when styling the glyphs inside it.

Comment: I think this would work too. But, as I've already done it the other way, I'm not going to bother trying to do it again... thanks! Couple ways to shave this poodle apparently.

Answer (score 1):

CSS class names can't contain the `:` symbol. Everything after the `:` will be interpreted as a pseudo-class (like `:hover`) and will not be parsed properly.

As for your classes, why do they all have to be unique? Classes are made to select multiple elements at once, so you can just do this:

```
<div class="glyph">Foo</div>
<div class="glyph">Foo</div>
<div class="glyph">Foo</div>
<div class="glyph">Foo</div>
```

And select them all with one selector:

```
.glyph {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: This is what it used to be, but I want to select all of the elements from a single box. Is there a way to do (getElementsByClassName) on a div that only returns its children the way you can on a document? I need the numbers to tell which box each thing belongs to: see http://gumonshoe.net/magic

Comment: If you can select that individual box and store it in a variable, `getElementsByClassName` still works: `document.getElementById('box').getElementsByClassName('glyph')`. It'd be easier with jQuery, though.

Comment: You can use colons, but have to properly escape them (you will learn this if you have to deal with the crap that is JSF created HTML. ;)